# Building the project in Visual Studio makes references stop working?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I don't even know how to describe this. I have a WPF project that I've added some libraries to. Libraries I've used in many other projects before. I have the strange issue of, when typing out code, intellisense can fill in things from a library fine, but as soon as I do a build, VS acts like all of these things are undeclared. Import statements suddenly say that I'm trying to reference things that don't exist, etc. But then if I clean the build, all of the references come back fine.

I'm completely stumped, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this if you are targeting the client profile, but some of the DLLs require the full .net framework.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are using file based references to libraries ($ref) that have corresponding projects in the same solution as the one you are adding references to ($proj).

Visual Studio is unable to (reliably) understand the build order and builds the items out of sequence (the $proj is built before the $ref, but after the $ref's output has been cleaned).

If you have this situation, just change the references to project based references.

Similarly, make sure there are no build events that would alter or move files.

Also, VS will sometimes search for a reference and pick a file at a location that you do not expect. Highlight the reference and check its property page, and make sure its actually where you think it is.

Comment: All good advice as I've seen reference in general have lots of little problems like that, but in this case it wound up being the DLL was built with a full version of .NET, and the application was set to a client Profile version